# Requests of Test Connection to MySQL DB is failing in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a request to enter DB connection details and a then click on the Test Connection button. But somehow it is failing in Jmeter. All i am getting is "System encountered an issue while processing request, please contact administrator for further info" in the response body[image: Error while testing connection to MySQL DB]. Nothing is displayed in the debug console. And i can see all the request are related to MySQL DB namely "POST https://nvussjc-dvqa02:8443/AnalyticsDataView/tables","POST https://nvussjc-dvqa02:8443/AnalyticsDataView/saveConnectionDetails"..... But when i am performing the steps from application i don't see any error in Console. I have added the JDBC jar,JDBC connection configuration. And the JDBC request that i added for the same MySQL DB is passing[image]. So how can i find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't "click" any buttons, it acts on [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol level, if you can execute your scenario in browser and it fails in JMeter it means that JMeter doesn't send the same [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) as browser does.

Most probably your requests are failing due to missing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), in the absolute majority of cases you cannot replay recorded script without prior modification. Modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for i.e. [client side state tracking](https://meeraacademy.com/viewstate-example-in-asp-net) or [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern) so my expectation is that you need to carefully inspect your requests, identify the dynamic parameters and use suitable JMeter [PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) for extracting them from the server responses.

See [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) article for more information.